# Proof of Bloch theorem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, eigenvalue

On many websites, it is written that translation operator $\hat{T}$ commutes with Hamiltonian $\hat{H}$, and thus they share the same eigenstates:

$\hat{H} |\psi> = E |\psi>$,

$\hat{T} |\psi> = \lambda |\psi>$.

By the way, I learned there is a simultaneous eigenstate if "helmitian" operators $\hat{A}, \hat{B}$ commute with each other. I know the expression of $\hat{T} (a)$ is $\exp (- i \frac{a}{\hbar} \hat{p})$. It is "not" helmitian.

Why we can say there is a simultaneous eigenstate of $\hat{T}$ and $\hat{H}$? I don't understand the reason at all.

Thank you in advance.

---

One of the websites I visited is this: http://web.mit.edu/6.730/www/ST04/Lectures/Lecture19.pdf

Comment: A more general version of the theorem you quoted  applies to normal operators, which include Hermitian and unitary operators.

Comment: 1. The word is [Hermitian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_matrix), not helmitian. 2. A proof of the statement "Two (diagonalizable) operators that commute have a simultaneous eigenbasis, without any need for Hermiticity, can be found e.g. in https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/104674/50583 or https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/259386/50583